# Google Actions deployed

Tags: actions-on-google

My Google Action was approved by Reviewer team and it showing deployed on Action console. but users not able to use it and only I can use it in my mobile and that is also test version. What does deployed mean? Will it take some time to reflect?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once deployed, it does take some time to roll out to all Google servers to be available to everyone. During this time you'll still get it reported as tests.

It should be available to everyone within a few hours.

Comment: It's 3 days ago. But users still not able to use it.

Comment: 3 days seem longer than expected, particularly after its been approved. You should [use the form on this page](https://developers.google.com/actions/support) to contact support.